# Remove or Modify Header Information in EML File

Tags: php

i`d like to modify the header information of that eml file with php:

I want to Remove the Line Message-ID and i want to change the Mail adresses in the Line To. For Example, delete all 3 mail adresses and replace it with one other ...

Can somebody help me?

```
Received: from server.local (7.6.19.14) by mail.local
 (192.168.0.1) with Microsoft SMTP Server id 8.3.298.1; Fri, 19 Jul 2013
 08:38:42 +0200
Received: by server.local (Postfix, from userid 1)  id 62C961608B7; Fri, 19
 Jul 2013 08:38:42 +0200 (CEST)
From: "mail@example.com" <mail@example.com>
To: Recipient <test@test.de>, Recipient <test@test.de>, 
Recipient <test@test.de>
Date: Fri, 19 Jul 2013 08:38:42 +0200
Subject: EG...
Thread-Topic: EG...
Thread-Index: Ac6ESpw8LCpOq4iNTOa02MkB6MTlsQ==
Message-ID: <20130719063842.62C961608B7@mail.local>
Accept-Language: en-US
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: mail.local
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="_002_2013074498405156741_"
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for showing us what an email header looks like... can you show us what you've done in an attempt to accomplish your goal?

Comment: [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php) and [preg_replce](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php) should do it. please check the manual for it and look for some tutorials in [regexp](http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-regular-expression.html) if needed

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively simple preg_replace problem.... this should give you what you need.

```
$email = preg_replace('/^Message-ID: .*\n/m','', $email);
$email = preg_replace('/^To :(.*)\n/m', 'To: $1\n', $email);
```

Comment: **The Frist line works great, but the second must look like this, i think?**  

    $email = preg_replace('/^To: (.*)\n/m', '', $email); 

**But when the To-Attribute has to lines:**  

To: Recipient <test@test.de>, Recipient <test@test.de>,   
Recipient <test@test.de>  

**I get the following result when executing the code:**
From: "mail@example.com" <mail@example.com>  
Recipient <test@test.de>  <---- That Line must be deleted too
Date: Fri, 19 Jul 2013 08:38:42 +0200

Comment: No i found a tricky solution: 

$emailx=file_get_contents("test.eml");
$emailx=explode("\n\n",$emailx);
$email=$emailx[0];
$email = preg_replace('/^Message-ID: .*\n/m','', $email);
$email = preg_replace('/^To: (.*\n)*Date:/m', "To: recipient@newmail.de\nDate:", $email);
$cc=$email."\n\n".$emailx[1];
file_put_contents("test1.eml",$cc);

But i had to explode after \n\n because apache crashes if the string (whole mail) is too big ... is there a better solution?